# Windows Powershell format single colum into several depending on string contents

Tags: powershell

I need to make a report better readable. There is this third party tool that can retrieve if one specific setting is true or false and it checks every single user once on different domains and then puts the result one after another in a single column in my csv.
    I need to be able to split the output lines into different csv-columns depending on the domain for that user.

```
$var1 = "C:\location\filewithallsettings.csv"
. C:\mytool.exe\ show setting > $var1
```

then to only retrieve the "TRUE" ones:

```
Select-String -Path C:\filewithallsettings.csv -Pattern "enabled:true" |`
select-object -property Line|
Export-Csv -Path C:\filewithTRUEsettings.csv -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";" `
-NoTypeInformation
```

The output looks like this per line:

```
User1@domain.org has this setting enabled:true
User2@anotherdomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User3@thirddomain.org has this setting enabled:true
```

Now I cant get past that but I need to somehow analyze that second file strings and put every line from there into a specific column in another file depending on the domain for one user. I assume again with select-string or with $varname.contains() but I just dont know how.
    My goal is a file like that:

```
    DOMAIN   ANOTHERDOMAIN   THIRDDOMAIN   andsoon
    User1    User2           User3
```

remember...my tool only gives one column! 
    thank you in advance!!

EDIT
I copy the contents of filewithallsettings.csv into this post. Double Users are not relevant as there cannot be two same addreses on one domain. A single real user on different domains is also not relevant, I know there are some and which.

```
User1@domain.org has this setting enabled:true
User2@domain.org has this setting enabled:false
User3@domain.org has this setting enabled:true
User4@domain.org has this setting enabled:false
User1@anotherdomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User2@anotherdomain.org has this setting enabled:false
User3@anotherdomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User4@anotherdomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User1@thirddomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User1@thirddomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User2@thirddomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User3@thirddomain.org has this setting enabled:true
```

there is no header just the lines one below the other. The expected output is exactly this, because I cannot change how the tool works. But I thought I can create another csv where you have only the TRUEs, which are the only ones need to be reviewed. OK this I got done by doing the above select-string and I get the same style of file, this time without the FALSEs and the header "Line"

```
Line `
User1@domain.org has this setting enabled:true
User2@domain.org has this setting enabled:true
User3@domain.org has this setting enabled:true
User1@anotherdomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User3@anotherdomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User4@anotherdomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User1@thirddomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User1@thirddomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User2@thirddomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User3@thirddomain.org has this setting enabled:true
```

I want to search in EVERY line and depending on which domain there is it should put that whole line in a csv under the column header for the said domain like in my first post.

Comment: Could you give a few more sample input and output scenarios? What would you like, for example, if you have more than one user on the same domain? Two domains with two users and one domain with one user? Answering the question as it is now would require making assumptions on these questions, so it would probably save everyones time if you could give more examples. Perhaps also a sample input file (the file you have called `filewithallsettings.csv`) could be beneficial.

Comment: Yea sure I try:
My Tool sends one call to every single user for every single domain and retrieves the single setting "enabled:false" or "enabled:true" (I cannot tell which setting, I am sorry) and puts this as one line in a csv like this:
User xxx@firstdomain.org has xxxx enabled:true
User yyy@firstdomain.org has xxxx enabled:false
User yyy@firstdomain.org has xxxx enabled:false
User yyy@firstdomain.org has xxxx enabled:true
User yyy@firstdomain.org has xxxx enabled:true

Comment: Yea sure I try:
My Tool sends one call to every single user for every single domain and retrieves the single setting "enabled:false" or "enabled:true" (I cannot tell which setting, I am sorry) and puts this as one line in one column of a csv like this:
User xxx@firstdomain.org has xxxx enabled:true
User yyy@firstdomain.org has xxxx enabled:false
User yyz@firstdomain.org has xxxx enabled:false
User yzy@seconddomain.org has xxxx enabled:true
User xyy@thirddomain.org has xxxx enabled:true
and this goes until eleventh domain with between 100 and 2000 users per domain
I need to fomrat it like above

Comment: it is just to be better readable and to avoid excel clicking in that csv, I know you can split this one output line into several columns with excel. But you should be able to do it with PS aswell

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not answer the questions I posed. Could you please edit the question and add the following: 1) Expected output when there are more than one user in each domain and also not the same amount of users in each domain 2) A sample `filewithallsettings.csv` (with perhaps 10 or 15 sample lines with email address and enabled:true and enabled:false), along with the _expected output for that data_,so that someone who tries to help you can use the sample data you provide. And please edit your question to add this information instead of providing it in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, I'd say that it feels as though csv is a strange format for this data, since the data on each column on a single line does not have anything to do with the other data on the same line. To get the PowerShell cmdlet `Export-Csv` to create such a CSV file we thus have to create object where the different properties on each object does not have any relation to the other properties on the same object.

That being said, here is a very quick solution (the first one that came to my head, meaning that it is likely that there are a lot (of) better ways to solve this) which you could use and alter to your liking:

```
$content = @"
User1@domain.org has this setting enabled:true
User2@domain.org has this setting enabled:false
User3@domain.org has this setting enabled:true
User4@domain.org has this setting enabled:false
User1@anotherdomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User2@anotherdomain.org has this setting enabled:false
User3@anotherdomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User4@anotherdomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User1@thirddomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User1@thirddomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User2@thirddomain.org has this setting enabled:true
User3@thirddomain.org has this setting enabled:true
"@

$fileContent = $content -split [Environment]::Newline
#In your scenario, the above line should be replaced with the next line
#$fileContent = Get-Content C:\filewithallsettings.csv -Encoding UTF8

$usersByDomain = 
    $content -split [Environment]::Newline | 
    #Start by selecting only the lines you want, using a regex which captures the user info
    Select-String -Pattern "(.*)@([^ ]*) .*enabled:true" |
    #Then convert these regex matches into object, making them easier to work with
    Foreach {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Username  = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
            Domain = $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value
        }
    } |
    #Then group them by the domain name
    Group Domain

$longestUserListCount = ($usersByDomain | Measure -Property Count -Maximum).Maximum

#Since we want to create a very strange format where the properties on each object does not have
#anything in common with the other properties on the same object, we want to turn the groups 
#sideways (to get domains as properties and each object ("line") to hold usernames for the 
#aforementioned properties.
$result = @()
for($index = 0; $index -lt $longestUserListCount; $index++)
{
    $properties = @{}
    foreach($domain in $usersByDomain)
    {
        #If the domain has this many users, add the username as the property value, otherwise add 
        #an empty string to get all lines to have the same properties
        if ($index -lt $domain.Count)
        {
            $properties[$domain.name] = $domain.Group[$index].UserName
        }
        else
        {
            $properties[$domain.name] = ""
        }
    }
    $result += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
}

$result | Format-Table * 
$result | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation
#If you want to export it to a csv file instead, just remove the above two lines and uncomment the next
#Export-Csv c:\output.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Executing the above script will yield the following output:

For the `Format-Table`:

```
domain.org                 anotherdomain.org          thirddomain.org          
----------                 -----------------          ---------------          
User1                      User1                      User1                    
User3                      User3                      User1                    
                           User4                      User2                    
                                                      User3
```

For the `ConvertTo-Csv`:

```
"domain.org","anotherdomain.org","thirddomain.org"
"User1","User1","User1"
"User3","User3","User1"
"","User4","User2"
"","","User3"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this out and repost my results. On a side note: the CSV format is not exclusive its just that my third party tool can only output text characters and its normally directly run from the command prompt where it also shows the results.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me but I am very very new to programming in general. Thanks again for your response, I tried it out but it yields to strange results and I think I did not provide the correct information.

The columns in my expected output CSV are named customly by myself after the domain specific email adresses.

```
UK    DE    FR    IT
```

The third party tool gives me the following information which I can save into a variable and then make that variabel my first CSV

```
User1@DomainNameUK.org has this setting enabled:true 
User2@domainNameUK.org has this setting enabled:false
User3@DomainNameUK.org has this setting enabled:false
User1@DomainNameDE.org has this setting enabled:false
User2@DomainNameDE.org has this setting enabled:true
User3@DomainNameDE.org has this setting enabled:true
this goes on until the last (11.) domain and approx. 5000 Users
```

again: that first CSV does not have a column header, it could also be a normal .txt file

Now I need exactly match every of the above lines in a final expected output CSV which would like this:

```
UK                                                     DE
--                                                     --
User1@DomainNameUK.org has this setting enabled:true   User3@DomainNameDE.org has this setting enabled:true
                                                       User2@DomainNameDE.org has this setting enabled:true
```

Like depending on everything after the @ in every line of my first output it puts the complete line in the expected output csv under the specific column. First would be check if "enabled:true" is there and if yes then check what is the domain name and if domain name is "DomainNameUK" then put the complete line you just checked into C:\expectedOutput.csv under that column like above